Bind member variables in a table
I'm trying to simplify some repetitive code by building a table of members.
Let's say I have some structures and some code to manipulate these structures as follows. There could be additional structures (DataC, DataD, etc.) and corresponding process functions for each one.
struct DataA
{
    int a;
    double b;
    std::string c;
};

struct DataB
{
    double one;
    int two;
};

template<typename T>
void dothis(int index, T& val);

template<typename T>
void dothat(int index, T& val);

void processthis(DataA& a)
{
    int index = 0; // Index is 1-based
    dothis(++index, a.a);
    dothis(++index, a.b);
    dothis(++index, a.c);
}

void processthat(DataA& a)
{
    int index = 0; // Index is 1-based
    dothat(++index, a.a);
    dothat(++index, a.b);
    dothat(++index, a.c);
}

void processthis(DataB& b)
{
    int index = 0;
    dothis(++index, b.one);
    dothis(++index, b.two);
}

void processthat(DataB& a)
{
    int index = 0;
    dothat(++index, b.one);
    dothat(++index, b.two);
}

As you can see, it's get pretty repetitive quickly. Plus, it's error prone as the order of the variables matter and they must match in both processthis and processthat. The order may or may not be the same as in the structure.
My thought is that I can generalize the processthis and processthat functions by creating some kind of table of the member variables. That way the list of members in the proper order can be listed just once instead of 3 times for each data structure. I need something similar to the Descriptor/Definition anyway. Something like the following pseudocode:
struct Descriptor
{
    std::string name;
    somereferencetomember value;
};

struct DefinitionA
{
    constexpr static std::array def = std::to_array<Descriptor>
        ({
            {"a", &DataA::a},
            {"b", &DataA::b},
            {"c", &DataA::c},
        });
};

struct DefinitionB
{
    constexpr static std::array def = std::to_array<Descriptor>
        ({
            {"one", &DataB::one},
            {"two", &DataB::two},
        });
};

template<typename T, typename D>
void processthis(T& data, const D& definition)
{
    int index = 0;
    for( const auto& member : D::def )
        dothis(++index, member.value);
}

template<typename T, typename D>
void processthat(T& data, const D& definition)
{
    int index = 0;
    for( const auto& member : D::def )
        dothat(++index, member.value);
}

I thought of some kind of std::bind/std::function and even std::apply, but haven't quite worked out how to handle the various types. Any of the code except for the original data structs (DataA, DataB, etc.) can be changed.
Any thoughts? I can use C++20, boost, etc.

check out boost::pfr looks like it has all features you need.

Write a script in your favorite scripting language, that takes a list of members as input, and generates C++ source files defining the structs and accompanying boilerplate.

std::variant+ std::vist

boost::pfr looks amazing. Somethings are out of order in the structure, but it looks like I can remap the order with std::index_sequence. That's a bit of maintenance headache perhaps, but doable.

You might work with std::tuple and variadic template:
auto as_tuple(DataA& a) { return std::tie(a.a, a.b, a.c); }
auto as_tuple(DataB& b) { return std::tie(b.one, b.two); }

and then
template <typename T>
void processthis(T& t)
{
    int index = 0; // Index is 1-based
    std::apply([&](auto&... args){ (dothis(++index, args), ...); }, as_tuple(t));
}

Demo
